# Re-bind UI after SuppressChangeNotifications

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, reactiveui

If I do the following in my ViewModel:

```
using( SuppressChangeNotifications() )
{
  SomeString = "Fred";
  SomeNumber = 2;
}
```

Is there a way to refresh the UI to reflect the current data (without using property notifications). The reason I ask is because in my ViewModel property change notifications are being used to automatically save data and I don't want this behaviour while the data is being loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Sound like you should prioritise your subscriptions, as in, only subscribe to the changes when you're ready for them. `SuppressChangeNotifications` is useful when you're doing a lot of work at once and you want to handle those changes all at once.

But it's hard to say what you're exactly trying to accomplish without a more thorough example.